# How to set mintinstall to prompt for super user password from non sudoer account?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, sudo

I have two users in linux mint 18.02 xfce: adm - sudoer,  and user (desktop user) that is not sudoer.
When starting gparted or "users and groups" from user - adm password is asked: 
Autentification as super user us required to perform that action.
When starting software manager (mintinstall): 
 enter Your password to perform administrative tasks 
 is displayed - 
so I could not use it from user account.

Is it possible to set software manager to ask for super user password, like gparted do, like it is in xubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

[ktsuss](https://github.com/nomius/ktsuss) may be able to do what you want. If I remember correctly, when it is called, you can select which user you want to run the command as:

`$ ktsuss mintinstall`

It should be available in the default repositories:

`$ sudo apt install ktsuss`